# How to open the app in the background after some interval

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am building an iOS application in SWIFT where user location is fetched and sent to the server after every 30 mins. When the app is opened it keeps sending the location lat/long to the server but when the app is closed or suspended it won't send. I want to send the location even the app is closed. Is this somehow possible? I just want to send the location to server no need to open the app again and again?

Comment: https://medium.com/@calvinlin_96474/ios-11-continuous-background-location-update-by-swift-4-12ce3ac603e3 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app needs to support Background Tasks for being able to run in background.

I believe this has been answered multiple times. Here is the [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23)

Since you are using location, I would recommend you to use **UIBackgroundModes** as locations.But be sure you don't drain the users battery.

Also usage of background fetch (UIBackgroundModes - fetch) and silent notification can be a great way to get you app running after equal interval of time.

**Update**

For performing operations you can use silent notification - refer this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)

As per documentation - the system wakes your app in the background and calls the  `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`

**Update 2**

For local notification along with scheduling custom action refer this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1). But I really doubt this will help you achieve your desired result. Mainly because you app would get an event only when the user performs any action on your local notification and if he ignores it, you app will remain in background.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your detailed response. I have already implemented the Background Location Update when the app is in the background or not suspended. I also implemented the push notification which is showing after the time interval but how to execute the code when a notification is shown. I don't have an issue whether the app is shown or not after the push notification.

Comment: I want to just call an api when a notification is shown to update the location lat/long.

Comment: how to implement it on local push notification as my app is sending a local notification after every 30 mins.